# Why am I getting an IllegalArgumentException when creating a Map?

Tags: java, collections, java-9

I'm trying to create a map of cities and temperature, but it's throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`. Here's what I'm doing:

```
Map<String, Integer> tempMap = Map.of("London", 13, "Paris", 17, "Amsterdam", 13, 
                                      "Madrid", 21, "Rome", 19, "London", 13, "Bonn", 14,
                                      "Moscow", 7, "Barcelona", 20, "Berlin", 15);
```

If I add them one by one there's no problem:

```
Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new Hashmap<>(); // or LinkedHashMap
tempMap.put("London", 13);
tempMap.put("Madrid", 21);
tempMap.put("Moscow", 7);
// etc.
```

Why does this happen? Aren't the contents supposed to be the same?

Comment: are you answering your own question from the 3-rd person? :)

Comment: got me excited then, was about to post an answer until I saw yours ^^.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I'm trying a new style which is less boring :)

Comment: Isn't the reason described in the message of the exception? (Not to mention the Javadoc?)

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh yes [I know... I know...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357495/require-clarification-on-the-amount-of-research-a-question-needs-in-order-not-to). Apparently it's good to ask questions that have their answers trivially available.

Comment: The linked meta question's top and accepted answer says "Lack of research effort is not, and has never been, a reason to close a question. It is, however, a reason that one might see fit to downvote a question." That means it is not *good* to ask such questions, it is just not a reason to close them...

Comment: @Chris If you read the whole answer you'll see that this type of question is considered good. I was the one that asked the question.

Comment: I've reread the answer and I still don't see how you take that away from it but not my job to police stack overflow and the voting seems more in your favour than mine. :) I am curious though - does it really only complain about a duplicate if you put it in the constructor but attempts to add duplicates afterwards works fine?

Comment: @Chris Sorry, it was in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357495/require-clarification-on-the-amount-of-research-a-question-needs-in-order-not-to#comment520417_357505). Truth is it *is* a bad question. It's lazy and the docs clearly answer it. I'm only asking it because I was told these questions are good. I'm the one who complained about the `List` question and generated mild controversy in first place. I also find it pitiful that the answer is my 3rd highest voted while it is hardly useful. I guess now if someone reads this comment they will do an ironic downvote.

Comment: @Chris The `Map.of` is the new Java 9 immutable collections API. They are implemented through internal classes, not the known ones. If you try to add to that same map later it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. The 2nd example uses the mutable (regular) map, so you can add entries freely.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that it was your meta question and assumed this was probably the reason for you asking as a sort of protest. Its also why once I realised you were getting positive votes I figured I'd not bother going on about it any more. :)

Comment: Oh, a meta meta question…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because you have a duplicate key in your instantiation: `"London"`. The [immutable static factories](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#immutable) for `Map` and `Set` do not allow duplicates (a map entry is duplicate if its key is duplicate) - not during creation time - therefore not at all. The restriction is manifested by a thrown `IllegalArgumentException`.

Although technically you're not doing anything incompatible, the writers of the library assumed that it's a (probably copy-paste) mistake. Why would you add an item just to override it a few lines later?

Which brings me to...

> If I add them one by one there's no problem

That's what you think, only you might not have realized that your map will contain 1 entry less than you put in it. The duplicate entry overrides the previous one ("last one wins" rule). When a bug will happen because of this there are going to be a lot of question marks thrown around. For this reason, the *fail-fast* method has its advantages (though I won't advocate it's just plain better).

As a tip, when creating the map it's easier to see its content if you format it a bit:

```
Map<String, Integer> tempMap = Map.of(
        "London",    13,
        "Paris",     17,
        "Amsterdam", 13,
        "Madrid",    21,
        "Rome",      19,
        "London",    13, // !
        "Bonn",      14,
        "Moscow",     7,
        "Barcelona", 20,
        "Berlin",    15
);
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in **[Map.of()](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)**

> They reject duplicate keys at creation time. Duplicate keys passed to
>   a static factory method result in `IllegalArgumentException`.

Since, each odd-number parameters are keys and even-number are values of for the `Map`. You need to make sure that odd-number parameter are unique.

On the other hand, [`Map.put`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) will replace the old value for same key.